# How to retrieve source documents based on score using LangChain Python

Tags: python, langchain, opensearch

LangChain query returns chunks of the documents indexed based on score.
But my requirement is to return the source of the document(containing the matching chunks) with best average score to the matching query.
Ex: If I search for 'Aws Certification details' , I want to return the source of the document with best average score to the matching query returned in hierarchical order.
Please help with, if LanChain has API support for it, or need to be custom built

I tried to use LangChain similarity_search_with_score API, it returns the best chunks of the documents I indexed with score hierarchically, which matches the query.
My expectation is to get the source of the document with best average score , which matches the input query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.